# Warp with skimage too slow

Tags: python, scikit-image, affinetransform

(Taking a chance at not posting an example here but I think the question is general enough that one is not necessary.)

I am using `skimage.transform.warp` to warp a 200x2000 image given 500 source and destination control points calculated with `skimage.transform.PiecewiseAffineTransform`. When I run this on a single image, it takes about 3 seconds. Is this a reasonable runtime for this calculation in everyone's experience?

The reason I ask is that I have potentially hundreds of images of the same dimensions that I want to apply the same inverse transform to but this will take waaaaay too long. If I use Python's `multiprocessing` module, the calculation hangs and never completes.

What I would like to do is run `warp` on a single image and then calculate a polynomial that defines the value of each pixel in the warped image given the values of all 400000 pixels in the input image. Mathematically:

`f'(x,y) = a0_0*f(0,0) + a0_1*f(0,1) + ... + a200_1999*f(200,1999) + a200_2000*f(200,2000)`

Does anyone have a recommendation as to how would I go about doing this or something similar or implementing something faster?

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe [`warp_coords`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.transform.html#warp-coords) is what you're looking for?

Comment: Consider trying OpenCV for this task

Comment: @MarkRansom Warp works exactly as I want it to, it's just slow.

Comment: @soupault How would I do it with OpenCV?

Comment: The point is that `warp_coords` creates something that can be reused over and over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into a similar issue when I had to correct some images from a spectroscopic camera. I ended up using [`sp.ndimage.map_coordinates`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.interpolation.map_coordinates.html). You have to build a function that transforms your source point coordinates into destination coordinates (`dummy` function in the example below). I understand from the question this transformation is the same for a bunch of images, and that you already have this function.

Then you generate a full grid of coordinates, and `map_coordinates` will map your original image onto these new coordinates trough spline interpolation.

```
from scipy.ndimage import map_coordinates

# stack of 10 images
imgs=np.random.normal(size=[10,200,2000])
x, y = np.arange(imgs.shape[1]), np.arange(imgs.shape[2])
ini_coord=np.meshgrid(x, y)

# dummy function transforms source points into destination points
def dummy(ini_coord):
    return [0.9*x.T for x in ini_coord]
out_coord=dummy(ini_coord)

import time
tt=time.clock()
out_img=np.zeros(imgs.shape)
for i, img in enumerate(imgs):   
    out_img[i]=map_coordinates(img, out_coord, mode='nearest')

print('{:3f} s'.format(time.clock()-tt))
```

This runs in less than 1 sec. on my computer

Comment: I am having trouble doing this with a polynomial transformation estimated by `skimage`. I run `tform = transform.estimate_transform('polynomial', dst, src, order=2)`. Do you think I can apply `tform` in a similar way as you did above? Thank you

Comment: @Simone I think so, you would have to replace `dummy` by your `tform`, rest should be the same

Comment: Thanks. I cannot actually find the transformation function out of `tform`, I will try a bit harder then.

Comment: I guess not. It does not work if I substitute it to `dummy`. I guess it is a class.